# Redirect all directory's except for root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for a redirect too let the home of the domain stay where it is. All subdirectories I want to redirect to another domain with the same URL but a different domain.

I found some solutions that did not do the job: everything is redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This one looks not what I am looking for although the name suggests it does.
[redirect all pages except root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346240/redirect-all-pages-except-root)

I want domain.com stays on my server but everything after the domein is redirected to domain2.com.
So domain.com/contact go's to domain2.com.contact

Answer (score 0):

This should be as straight forward as this when looking at your example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?. https://example2.com${REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

However it is not clear from your question what you actually mean by "subdirectories". Please note that the example you yourself give and say that it *should* get redirected does *not* look like a "subdirectory". So maybe you want to revise your question in that detail...

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).